# Good/clean practice for building the auth part of an application

Tags: authentication, login, users

I'm starting on a greenfield project and haven't done or architected the sign-up/sign-in and auth part of the backend in a very long time, so my knowledge on the nowadays' good practices is very limited. I've basically only done basic local sign-up/sign-in functionality.

The app is related to social networking, so thousands of users might be expected in proximity of a few years. Therefore I want to start off with as clean of architecture as possible, obviously. But also trying to "look into the future" and anticipate costs.

Now, for the project I need to have sign-up/log-in options with:

- mobile phone nr.
- email
- Apple account
- Facebook account

I'm looking into managed services like Auth0, AWS Cognito (particularly interested in this one), etc.

But I'm uncertain whether I understand how the process and user account management should be set up. Provided I use a relational DB, do I still need to create the user account models in my application and then:

- when a user signs up thru email - my app handles all the auth, including sign-in and access/refresh token generation and handling.
- when a user signs up thru any other 3rd party means - I use the managed auth service and link the user record in the service to a user record in my DB. Then use the managed service for token generation and handling.

Or, do I delegate the whole user management (including the user account models & data) to the managed auth service? And thus, the only functionality related to auth and user account management in my application will be calls to the managed auth service...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you always have to create your own identity (user model with an ID), to unify user management across several identity providers.

Then you *map* your users to different identity providers: local (email and password), OAuth, Auth0, anything else.

If a user wants to also login via another identity provider, or loses access to one of them, they don't also lose access to your site.